# How can I generate the link to the AppStore for Windows dynamically

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to generate the link to the AppStore for Windows and set it as a link inside my app for some reason. How can I get it before I upload the App so that I can include it in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft predefined Marketplace detail task for Windows Phone 8, [Here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: :- I want to get the link to the Store so that I can mail it inside the app. Can I get it through MarketPlace.

Comment: Here you go, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967553(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To show the Details page of your App in the Windows Phone Store, use the [MarketplaceDetailTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacedetailtask) without a `ContentIdentifier`:

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

To show the Review Page you should use the [MarketplaceReviewTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacereviewtask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
MarketplaceReviewTask marketplaceReviewTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
marketplaceReviewTask.Show();
```